# Don't show array elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have one array that I want to show in a modal.

The array does have the elements as I have tested this, but it doesn't appear in the modal.

This is the code:

```
    <script>
        var selected_items = [];
        var i = 0;

        function LoadItems() {
            for(var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                document.write('<li>' + skins_selected[j] + '</li>');
            }
        }

function UpdateArray(name) 
{   
        selected_items[i] = name;
        i++;
}
    </script>

    <div class="modal fade" id="modalItems" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="labelItems">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="labelItems">¿Confirma que desea depositar los siguientes items?</h4>
                </div>

                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <ul>
                            <script>
                                LoadItems();
                            </script>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button onclick="mostrar()" class="btn btn-info">Depositar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                </div>

                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

P.S: If I put:

```
<script>
    function LoadItems() {
        (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            document.write(j);
        }
    }
</script>
```

it shows me "01234", but when I put the array it doesn't show me anything.

Comment: Where are you defining the object skins_selected?

Comment: You have assigned 0 to `i`, then you are using that as the limiting condition. That's why it does not enter the loop even once. When you hardcode the value to 5, the loop runs as you mentioned.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I update the main code when the function that I use for put items in the array. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<ul>
                        <script>
                              var selected_items=[1,2,3,4,5];
                              var i = 5;

                              function LoadItems() {
                                for(var j = 0; j < selected_items.length; j++) {
                                  document.write('<li>' + selected_items[j] + '</li>');
                                }
                            }
                            LoadItems();
                        </script>
                    </ul>
```

your loop is not executing because `for(var j = 0; j < i; j++)` where `j=0 and i=0`, so `j < i` it can be like that.

you should declare `i = 5` not `i = 0`;

Also your array is empty, please put something in your array **like**

`var items_selected = [1,2,3,4,5];`

Comment: Hi, I try this and don't work: `function LoadItems()
{
 for(var j = 0; j < selected_items.length; j++)
 {
  document.write('<li>' + selected_items[j] + '</li>');
 }
}`

Comment: check the updated answer, put the `that code in your modal`

Comment: The problem is that I put items on the array in other functions that I have more above. I updated the main code to see the problem.

Comment: but in your question you haven't shown your array function, you just shown it empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is looping through the array `i` times. However, on the previous line `i` is set to 0. So it's looping 0 times, which is why you get nothing displayed.

I assume you want it to loop through all the items in the array, regardless of how 
many elements there are. In that, case you should use the .length property of the skins_selected array:

```
function LoadItems() {
    for(var j = 0; j < skins_selected.length; j++) {
        document.write('<li>' + skins_selected[j] + '</li>');
    }
}
```

You can dispense with the `i` variable entirely.

Comment: Hi, I try this and don't work: `function LoadItems()
{
 for(var j = 0; j < selected_items.length; j++)
 {
  document.write('<li>' + selected_items[j] + '</li>');
 }
}`

Comment: @R.Rio what _exactly_ doesn't work? What you've posted in your comment is not the code I gave in my example. From the update you've just made to the question it appears you have got two completely different arrays - selected_item and skins_selected. What's the relationship between them?

Comment: the function, don't show the array elements that I have it. I update the main code to the function that I use to put elements in the array

Comment: @R.Rio When is the UpdateArray() method triggered? And anyway, it would appear that LoadItems() within your modal is being run when the _page loads_, not when the modal is displayed to the user.

Comment: Now I understand the problem. How I can update the modal when this is displayed to the user?

Comment: @R.Rio Assuming you are using bootstrap 3, you can put the following JS code somewhere in your page: `$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#modalItems').on('shown.bs.modal', function() { LoadItems();});});`. And remove the call to LoadItems from within your HTML markup.

Comment: @R.Rio Also you need to modify the LoadItems function slightly so that it inserts data into the DOM in the right place: Instead of `document.write('<li>' + skins_selected[j] + '</li>');` put `$("#modal-ul).append('<li>' + skins_selected[j] + '</li>');`. Lastly, change the following markup: `<ul>
                            <script>
                                LoadItems();
                            </script>
                        </ul>` to this: `<ul id="modal-ul">
                        </ul>`

Answer (score 0):

You are initially setting i, your loop exit condition, to 0. As a result your loop will never run. I.e. you are essentially saying:

```
for(var j=0; j < 0; j++){
    //j is never < 0 so this code never runs
}
```

Your second example removes this and hardcodes the loop exit condition to the expected value.

Comment: Hi, I try this and don't work: `function LoadItems()
{
 for(var j = 0; j < selected_items.length; j++)
 {
  document.write('<li>' + selected_items[j] + '</li>');
 }
}`

Comment: Are you adding anything to selected_items[] ?At the moment its length is still 0 so essentially the same thing is happening

Comment: I update the main code with the function that I use to put items in the array.

Comment: In which case I would include some debug statements/console.logs before the loop in your function to check that selected_items is correct before using it as the exit condition.